# How do I redirect a subdirectory to my Heroku app running python?

Tags: python, heroku, dns, subdirectory

i'm new to Python and Heroku.  I'd like to allow a user to type a url with a subdirectory and have that redirect to my Heroku app.  For example, a user should be able to type mydomain.com/upgrade into a browser and have it directed to my Horuku app hosted at say hello123.herokuapp.com.  I already have the domain redirect setup in the heroku dashboard to forward all requests to mydomain.com.  Though now i need /upgrade to redirect to my Heroku app.  In the future, i'd like different subdirectories such as mydomain.com/app1 and mydomain.com/app2 to point to different Heroku apps.

Any suggestions to get started?

Thank you

Comment: I would look into Flask, a lightweight web framework.

Comment: Hey there! This is a long shot, but did you find any way to do this? Or any other alternative on how to organize the structure? Thx :)